# Strange temporary folders in apache tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, buffer, temporary

Whenever I start apache tomcat, I have strange folder called buffer inside temp and the buffer contains 256 empty subfolder from b0-b255, So, the structure is

tomcat/temp/buffer/b0

tomcat/temp/buffer/b1

.

.

tomcat/temp/buffer/b255

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the teiid driver.

org.teiid.common.buffer.impl.FileStorageManager.java